# What is a regular expression that find a line like this: <rect **** />

Tags: regex, string, string-matching

I want a regular expression that could be used to find the following lines:

```
<rect width='10px' height ='20px'/>
<rect width='20px' height ='22px'/>
<circle radius='20px' height ='22px'/>
```

and replace them by the these lines:

```
<rect width='10px' height ='20px'></rect>
<rect width='20px' height ='22px'></rect>
<circle radius='20px' height ='22px'></circle>
```

Thank you .

Comment: What would this acccomplish, really?

Comment: I think if you desperately want that, read the XML with a proper parser and output it again after telling the parser not to use self-closing tags.

Comment: I know this one is linked too much, but I think in this case it's appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @poly: I use svg with "jquery svg" , it does not work if I write "/>" instead of "</rect>". I know it's the same. but jquery does not.
@Rossel: Thanks,it's a good idea.

Comment: so is this JavaScript, or server-side? What flavor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think regex is the right tool for this job, but something like this will "work" some of the time.

```
    String text =
        " <rect width='10px' height ='20px'/> \n" +
        " <rect width='20px' height ='22px'/> \n" +
        " <circle radius='20px' height ='22px'/> \n" +
        " <square/> <rectangle></rectangle> \n" +
        " <foo @!(*#&^#@/> <bar (!@*&(*@!#> </whatever>";
    System.out.println(
        text.replaceAll("<([a-z]+)([^>]*)/>", "<$1$2></$1>")
    );
```

The above Java snippet prints:

```
 <rect width='10px' height ='20px'></rect> 
 <rect width='20px' height ='22px'></rect> 
 <circle radius='20px' height ='22px'></circle> 
 <square></square> <rectangle></rectangle> 
 <foo @!(*#&^#@></foo> <bar (!@*&(*@!#> </whatever>
```

The regex is this ([see also on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/OT4xlZOOZC)):

```
/<([a-z]+)([^>]*)\/>/
```

Essentially we try to capture what we hope is a tag name in group 1, and everything else until the `/>` in group 2, and use these captured strings in our substitution.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like polygenelubricants noted I don't know what this would accomplish but this should be what you are looking for:

```
<rect[^>]*/>
```

and

```
<circle[^>]*/>
```

If you want to match any self-contained tag you should look at Crozins solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this `#<([a-z]+)([^>]*)/>#` and replace with `<$1$2></$1>`. But regexp might differ depending on what's regexp engine you're using.

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/<\([a-z]*\) \([^\/>]*\)\/>/<\1 \2><\/\1>/'`

Would do what you want (in this case)

Search pattern:
`<\([a-z]*\) \([^\/>]*\)\/>`

Replace pattern:
`<\1 \2><\/\1>`